# oracle update calculation from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE  a SET a.CRV_AMOUNT = ((b.BASELINE_TOTAL_VALUE * a.CRV_PERCENT) / 100)
 FROM RECAPT.COST_MODEL_DETAIL a, RECAPT.COST_MODEL b
WHERE a.COST_MODEL_ID = b.COST_MODEL_ID;
```

I get SQL Command not ended properly in oracle

Answer (score 0):

This is not Oracle syntax.  Another way:

```
UPDATE RECAPT.COST_MODEL_DETAIL a
    SET CRV_AMOUNT = (SELECT (b.BASELINE_TOTAL_VALUE * a.CRV_PERCENT) / 100
                      FROM RECAPT.COST_MODEL b
                      WHERE a.COST_MODEL_ID = b.COST_MODEL_ID
                     )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM RECAPT.COST_MODEL b
                  WHERE a.COST_MODEL_ID = b.COST_MODEL_ID
                 );
```

Comment: i get FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: Delete the last parenthesis from the second line, after 100. I will edit to fix.

Comment: NUMBER(26,20) is defined for amount but i get error  value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Comment: @mathguy  what if subquery at `SET` returns more than one row

Comment: @sql_dummy - then your entire model is wrong. You want to update a value in your first table by looking up an id in the second table, but the id appears more than once in the lookup table? Do you understand why that is a logical problem in your setup? There is no reasonable way to solve this (if it happens) other than looking at the data model and figuring out what's wrong. That CAN'T happen if the model is correct!

Comment: What if in`RECAPT.COST_MODEL` the `COST_MODEL_ID` is not a primary key, but there is functional dependency just between `COST_MODEL_ID` and `BASELINE_TOTAL_VALUE`

Comment: I am new user i cannnot ask question for another day. and also CRV_PERCENT has NUMBER(26,20) and CRV_AMOUNT is defined NUMBER(26,20) also baseline_total_value is defined NUMBER(26,20) My question, What is the length i need to use for CRV_AMOUNT to get past the value larger than specified precision allowed for this column error

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you update data in a table based on data in another table, consider the `merge` statement instead of `update`. `merge` is more flexible, it can be used to update, insert and delete, all in one statement, and in some cases it may be more efficient than `update` or `insert`.

```
merge into recapt.cost_model_detail a
  using recapt.cost_model b
  on (a.cost_model_id = b.cost_model_id)
when matched then update
  set a.crv_amount = b.baseline_total_value * a.crv_percent / 100
;
```

Comment: NUMBER(26,20) is defined for amount but i get error value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Comment: @SujanTalurSuresh - What could that possibly have to do with the question you asked, or with the two solutions that were proposed so far? If you have no clue about precision and scale, and the NUMBER datatype and how it works, and you are getting a new error message (now that updating is working), **ask a new question** in a new thread!

Comment: I am new user i cannnot ask question for another day. and also CRV_PERCENT has NUMBER(26,20) and CRV_AMOUNT is defined NUMBER(26,20) also baseline_total_value is defined NUMBER(26,20) My question, What is the length i need to use for  CRV_AMOUNT to get past the value larger than specified precision allowed for this column error